# Compiler doesn't find methods from base class

Tags: c++, visual-studio, oop

I am having a problem with my virtual methods in a derived class. Here are my (simplified) C++ classes.

```
class Base
   virtual method accept( MyVisitor1* v ) { /*implementation is here*/ };
   virtual method accept( MyVisitor2* v ) { /*implementation is here*/ };
   virtual method accept( MyVisitor3* v ) { /*implementation is here*/ };

class DerivedClass
   virtual method accept( MyVisitor2* v ) { /*implementation is here*/ };
```

The following use causes VS 2005 to give: "error C2664: 'DerivedClass::accept' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'Visitor1*' to 'Visitor2 *'".

```
DerivedClass c;
MyVisitor1 v1;
c.accept(v1);
```

I was expecting the compiler to find and call Base::accept(MyVisitor1) for my DerivedClass as well. Obviously this is not working, but I don't understand why. Any ideas?

Thanks,

Paul

Comment: Does Derived class really derive from the Base class?  Is it public inheritance?  Are the methods in Base class also public?

Comment: You should probably supply some code that actually compiles. It looks like DerivedClass doesn't actually derive from Base, but since the supplied code isn't c++, we cannot know for sure.

Comment: Please post the actual code. Are you sure that you used public inheritance?

Comment: Sorry. It should read:

    class DerivedClass : public Base

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `accept` member of `DerivedClass` hides any members of the base class with the same name, even if they have different signatures. To include them, add the following to the definition of `DerivedClass`:

```
using Base::accept;
```

(I'm assuming that `DerivedClass` does derive from `Base`; your snippet doesn't explicitly say that).

Comment: This worked. I didn't know about this use of the keyword using. Thank you.